# What is the difference between an inner tail light assembly and an outer tail light assembly?

Tags: chevrolet, part-identification, tail-lights, impala

I'm trying to replace a passenger side tail light assembly (well, actually only the red plastic is broken, but that doesn't seem to come separately) for a 2015 Impala, and I see parts sites listing right/inner and right/outer as two separate things.  What do they mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tail lights on this car look like:

[image]
([image source](http://2015chevyimpala.com/2015-chevy-impala-photo-gallery/))

The outer assembly is the one on the quarter panel:

[image]

The inner assembly is the one on the trunk:

[image]

I'm 99% sure of this, but note that it *is* the result of a bunch of Google searching, and generic product pictures on parts sites make finding a clear image confusing.

If somebody could confirm this that'd be great. You could also call the dealer's parts department and ask.

Comment: I cannot confirm this, but it seems logical. I would bet you are spot on. I looked on my goto site. They don't have a picture of the part, but show the "outer" being more expensive than the inner, which would seem on part due to it being a bit larger. Looking at a couple of more things, I see on the [CAPA weekly listing for June 6, 2016](http://www.capacertified.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/P-6-Weekly-Parts-Update-060616.pdf), they show the part numbers GM2803109 and GM2802109 to be "On luggage lid", R and L respectively. This shows exactly what you're talking about.